# Can a car run on water? As per this experiment

Tags: road-vehicles, water, energy, pakistan

The Agha Waqar's car that ran on water was a great news for a long time. Where a Pakistan based inventor invented a car that got all the power from water.

He was using a **water kit** to get the energy.

Here is a WikiPedia page for that too: [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agha_Waqar%27s_water-fuelled_car)

I just wanted to know, how can such thing come to happen? If it was true, wouldn't America and other Developed countries have changed their power consumption to water? Is it really fake or not?

Comment: Should we consider questions about perpetual motion machines duplicates even if the specific perpetual motion machine hasn't been discussed? The answer 'the laws of thermodynamics don't allow perpetual motion machines' pretty much covers all of them.

Comment: It can't. He's claiming that he gets more energy from burning the electrolysis result than he expends running the electrolysis reaction. That's a pretty clear violation of the second law of thermodynamics. If he said you had to plug the car in to do the electrolysis, then run on the result, he'd be at least in the physically possible realm. As it's described on the linked wikipedia page, he's not doing what he says he's doing.

Comment: You'll be surprised, but there were two news stories in Russia about exactly the same thing about 7 and 15 years ago (usual story, some simple guys in Russian villages, "undiscovered genius", blah-blah-blah). Both times they were claiming it will revolutionize the energy market, but nothing happened... because both were clear-cut hoaxes.